# Python variable - how to declare it? UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Counter' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, twitter

I am starting on a Twitter bot and having a stupid problem declaring a variable, the code is very simple and stripped everything and it still does not work. When I run the code I get the following error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Counter' referenced before assignment
```

I have declared the variable as a global and in different location but still having the same problem.

```
global Counter

import tweepy, time

def search():
    Counter += 1
    print("Counter = " + Counter + "\n")
    time.sleep(60)

def run():
   search()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print "Running"f
   while True:
       run()
```

Comment: `global Counter = 0`. You have not assigned any value to `Counter`

Comment: You need to declare the counter global *where you use it*. There's no point putitng a `global` keyword in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

`global` should be used only within limited scopes (like a function) to indicate that you want `Counter` to reference the global object and **not** the local one.

Also, you need to initialize `Counter` with some value:

```
import tweepy, time

Counter = 0

def search():
    global Counter
    Counter += 1
    print("Counter = " + Counter + "\n")
    time.sleep(60)

def run():
   search()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print "Running"
   while True:
       run()
```

Answer (score 0):

`global` statement tells the code inside the block, to use a global variable context and not local one.

You still need to initialize this variable before addressing it.